# How can I restore the "Open or save as" prompt in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I often download temporary files. I don't want to save them anywhere permanent I just want to look at them and then have them go away automatically after I read them.

I am using Firefox 98.0.2 (64-bit) and in older versions of Firefox, I used to be able to do this by selecting "open" instead of "save as".  In a recent update, that dialog went away and I don't see a way to restore it. Now, instead, I have to save the files somewhere manually and then remember to delete them later (or manually navigate to temp, which is approximately as annoying).

This is the screen I want back:

[image]

Is there a way to restore this prompt?

Comment: *"I don't see a way to restore it."* - [It seems you may need to enable this for individual content types (e.g. `.pdf`) now.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manage-downloads-preferences-using-downloads-menu)

Comment: When you choose "Open with" the file is still saved quite permanently (into a `%TEMP%` location, but there is no process that cleans it up as far as I know).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into Preferences> General, and select the "Ask before opening" option for (in your example) Microsoft Word 98-2003 Document.

Comment: General information [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manage-downloads-preferences-using-downloads-menu) and a more complete overview on changing settings for individual content types [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_changing-download-actions).

Comment: I have changed every file type in that setting window to "always ask" and when I try to download a Ubuntu disk image via bittorrent, the .torrent file skips to the file-chooser dialog rather than showing the desired dialog.

Comment: Are `.torrent` files listed there? If not, you may wish to try right-clicking a downloaded `.torrent` file in the Downloads panel and choose "Always Open Similar Files". According to the Firefox documentation, the file will likely open in the system default application and a new Content Type entry should be added to the Applications section of Firefox settings, with the download action set to use that application. I would think you could change the settings to your preference afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I installed 98.0.2 to test this, it worked for me.

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel`
3. Double click the row to change it to false

[image: preview of setting]

Yes, it is an awful variable name.